# WPF toolkit bar charts, setting the column width programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, bar-chart, wpftoolkit

I am trying to programmatically  set the width of the column series in a WPF toolkit bar chart. Below is the existing code. But I am unable to set the width using ColumnDataPoint.WidthProperty.

Any suggestions would be of great help!

```
    Style columnStyleRed = new Style(typeof(ColumnDataPoint));
    columnStyleRed.BasedOn = this.Resources["CustomStyle"] as Style;
    Setter setBackgroundRed = new Setter(ColumnDataPoint.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed));
    Setter setWidth = new Setter(ColumnDataPoint.WidthProperty, 20);
    columnStyleRed.Setters.Add(setBackgroundRed);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same without any luck.

ATM, I'm looking at [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/documentation), which seems to play much nicer than the toolkit.

This seems to work :

```
<oxy:ColumnSeries ... ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... ColumnWidth="4"/>
```

It can also be done from the code if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly fix, I have the same problem, but My displays are going to be static as far as column numbers. I hard coded the margins in the template, that increased there widths.

```
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Stroke="Black"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                        Margin="0,0,-20,0"/>
                    <Grid
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Margin="0 -20 0 0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Yellow"        
                            Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                            FontSize="8"
                                    Margin="5,5,-20,2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```